# C# Switch Case with if statements not returning me the console.WriteLines

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, console.writeline

I am trying to create a simple switch case with If-Statements code.

#### Problem:

I don't get any value back.

#### For Example:

If I put int Temperature = 0; the Code should output "Es ist kalt". But my console doesn't display anything.

```
using System;

namespace SwitchCase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Temperatur = 25;

            switch (Temperatur)
     
            {
                    case 1:
                    if (Temperatur <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Es ist kalt");
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    if (Temperatur >= 25)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Es ist überdurchschnittlich warm");
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    if (Temperatur <= 13)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Es ist mild");
                    }
                    break;
                    
                


            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Just use the only input (`3`) that meets both `switch` cases and `if` conditions (like 1 is never less or equal than 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your if block never reaches a situation where `temperature` is 0.

you only have cases for temperatures 1, 2 and 3 (`case 1:`), so if temperature is anything else than those, nothing will happen.

Therefore, you should use `if`/`else` statements:

```
if (Temperatur <= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist kalt");
}
else if (Temperatur <= 13)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist mild");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist überdurchschnittlich warm");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make much sense. When `Temperatur` is exactly `1` or `2`, it cannot be less than or equal `0` nor greater than or equal `25`. So there's no way `Temperatur` has a value that gets any of the first two branches of the `switch` selected and additionally satisfies the `if` in that branch.

Just using `if` and `else if` does what you presumably want:

```
...
if (Temperatur <= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist kalt");
}
else if (Temperatur <= 13)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist mild");
}
else if (Temperatur >= 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist überdurchschnittlich warm");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You Just need if-statement:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      if (Temperatur <= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist kalt");
}
else if (Temperatur <= 13)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist mild");
}
else if (Temperatur >= 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Es ist überdurchschnittlich warm");
}
   }
}
```

Comment: would there be a way to combine switch with if in this case?

Comment: @DravenMain ,When you use if statements, you have to use dots too.The compiler will not connect the "dots" and understand that the "break;" statement inside your if statement is linked to the switch statement. Instead it will try to link it to a loop, since "break;" statements on their own can only be used with loops, to break out of it. That means that your case block is missing its break statement to complete it.